# unable to open database file on Azure App Service

Tags: python, azure, sqlite, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed my FlaskApp to Azure. I have a SQLLite db file, which opens on local, but on App Service it throws a message saying "Cannot Open the database file".
I have tried giving both absolute and full path but does not seem to work.

```
        DATABASE = "DBN\\LeaveApp.db"  # DB file initialization
        self.conn_db = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)  # connection opening  instantiation
        print("open database successfully")
        self.c = self.conn_db.cursor()
```

[image: File Structure]

On Azure App Service:

[image: App Service Folder Structure]

Any Idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, I have installed [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) in my local and created .db file.
  [image]
- Added sample data in my `pavandb.db` database. Then, created a flask app to retrieve the data from local.

**dbsample py:**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Connect to the SQLite database
    connection = sqlite3.connect('pavandb.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Execute the SQL query
    query = "SELECT name, age, salary FROM employees"
    cursor.execute(query)

    # Fetch the results
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    # Close the database connection
    connection.close()

    # Pass the results to the template and render it
    return render_template('index.html', results=results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

- Running successfully in my local.
  [image]
- Then deployed in App service (web app).
  [image]
- Now I can retrieve all the rows from the `employees` table in the `pavandb.db` database.
- Make sure that the `DBN` folder and the `pavandb.db` file are in the same directory as your Flask app file.
  [image]

Comment: Can you place your db file in a folder separately and then try? Like create folder like "Database", and then refer it "Database/pavandb"? it works locally, but not on App Service.

Comment: It won't work when it was in separate folders, try like the above.